# How do I plot data labels alongside my data in a bar graph

Tags: matlab, graph, bar-chart

I have a bar graph in which i would like to plot data labels alongside my data points. I have looked at this [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f0-4741.html#f0-19466) and they don't seem to have what i need. This is all done using MATLAB.

Below is an example of what i'd like, although for a bar graph instead of a scatter plot.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the `text()` function described in that link?

Comment: I used it, but it does not display in the graph. Note that, this is a subplot graph of two different graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Use TEXT function to label the bars. STRCAT function can be used to create custom labels.

```
x = (1:5)';
y = rand(5,1);
bar(x,y)
%# show X and Y coordinates
text(x,y,strcat('(',num2str(x),',',num2str(y,2),')'),...
     'horiz','center','vert','bottom')
```

You can also add some small gap to `y` coordinates to make text a little higher.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below and customize in your case.

```
for ii = 1:numel(X) 
        text(X(ii)+.02, Y(ii)+.02,textCell{ii},'FontSize',8) 
    end
```